# grep lines that have n occurrences of a given character

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a file with paths to files. For example looking like this:

```
/home/smth/a/file1
/home/smth/a/file2
/home/smth/b/file1
/home/smth/a/b/file1
```

I have a variable `F_COUNT=4` I want to select only lines, where the `'/'` character appears exactly `$F_COUNT` times.

It would return this:

```
/home/smth/a/file1
/home/smth/a/file2
/home/smth/b/file1
```

I tried using regex with `grep`, specifically i tried `grep "'/'\{0,$F_COUNT\}"` , but this doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: How would you do it without the variable?

Comment: Why are there additional quotes around the slash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) as requested :

```
F_COUNT=4
grep -E "^(/[^/]+){$F_COUNT}$" file
```

### Output :

```
/home/smth/a/file1
/home/smth/a/file2
/home/smth/b/file1
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `awk` to count fields:

```
F_COUNT=4
awk -F/ -v num="$F_COUNT" 'NF == num+1' file
```

```
/home/smth/a/file1
/home/smth/a/file2
/home/smth/b/file1
```